# Retaining objects in Objective C from a C programmer's point of view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pointers

Having programmed in C for 15+ years, I've recently started to work with Objective C and there's one thing that I don't really understand: Several methods return a pointer to an object but I don't own this object. Instead, people say that I need to retain this object for as long as I need to access it.

Let's take the return value of [NSTextField stringValue] as an example. This method will return an NSString to me. But I don't own this NSString, so if I want to work with it I'll have to retain it for as long as I need it, e.g.

```
NSString *s = [myTextField stringValue];
...              // why can't the object become invalid during this time?
[s retain];  
....             // do some work
[s release];
```

What is really puzzling me here is the time between the call to [myTextField stringValue] and [s retain]. I don't own the NSString, so who guarantees that the pointer to the NSString is still valid when I do the retain call in the third line of my code above?

The code above is of course very simple but as it has to be guaranteed that the "s" pointer is still valid when calling retain, doesn't it also have to be guaranteed that the pointer is still valid when I call retain on the string much later? Let's say 4 hours after calling [NSTextField stringValue]? I mean, I could even store the NSString pointer in a global variable and call retain on it much much later or is there a rule that retaining must happen in the current scope or really soon after getting the pointer and not 4 hours later? Still, it's difficult to understand how the Objective C compiler/runtime should keep track of all this.

From a C programmer's point of view it looks like retaining is somewhat superfluous in the code above because the pointer returned by [NSTextField stringValue] must stay valid anyway if it's possible to call [retain] on it. But that of course can't be the case. I'm sure it all makes sense once you get the idea but currently I'm still struggling to understand this because it's contradictory to what I've been doing in C all those years.

Hopefully there's somebody who can shed some light on this. Thanks!

Comment: Stop thinking about retains and releases and start thinking about ownership. Read about autoreleased objects. Note that autoreleased objects won't get released until the end of current run loop.

Comment: By naming convention, `stringValue` returns an autoreleased object.

Comment: I've read about autoreleasing of course but how can the autoreleaser know whether or not I'm still keeping a pointer to this NSString somewhere? I.e. how can the autoreleaser know when it is safe to release the object? It sounds almost impossible to me...

Comment: The you haven't read about autorelease pools, and more specifically when they are drained. "The Application Kit creates an autorelease pool on the main thread at the beginning of every cycle of the event loop, and drains it at the end, thereby releasing any autoreleased objects generated while processing an event."

Comment: Ok, thanks, now it's making sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm sure you know that retain and release are deprecated and with ARC we no longer need to burden ourselves with this stuff.

In your example you are making a new pointer: NSString *s and assigning it to point to the same address which your text field points to with its text property.  It is important to understand that s is scoped to this particular piece of code here, which is bordered by some curly brackets (braces). If you call retain on s you must release it as well inside this scope, because afterwards you no longer have the s pointer and you'll have a leak. 
But the object which s points to will stick around until the end of this scope anyway, so this retain/release pair are redundant.

If you do want to use this string at some undetermined point in the future then your pointer would need to be scoped to the entire instance, either as a property or an iVar. You could then call your retain as per your example and save releasing it until some time in the future, if the textField is deallocated the NSString object which its NSString *text property points to should survive because when the textField calls a release on it its reference count does not hit zero; you previously added one with your retain. So retain might be thought of as 'buy a share in this object' and release as 'sell my share in this object'. It is the object itself which determined to outlive the release message from the textField, which at that time was only one of its owners.

With all of that said, it would be a far more conventional approach to have made your own copy of the string at the time and many programmers would be critical if you were to just add a retain on an object which belongs to the UI (or anything).  The biggest trap with this sort of voodoo is that you can easily create a 'retain cycle' - an ownership loop, which can involve only two objects, but might just as easily be a complex graph. Retain cycles can be very difficult to track down so it's far better to just avoid them with good design.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I think I've understood it now although there is still a slight difference between the answers: Jef says that it is valid until the end of the scope it was received in whereas the doc quoted by Rob Mayoff (see below) says that it is valid throughout the complete method/function call...

Comment: Yes well Rob knows his stuff. I suspect method and scope in this case might be pretty much synonymous, the code which is a method or C function is usually contained in braces.  Please note that I was talking about the pointer *s, not the object itself. There are actually retain/release messages going on all the time under the hood as a mechanism to all that which is why Apple advise against checking the retainCount on an object implicitly, the runtime is constantly incrementing and decrementing it to make this stuff work

Comment: Yes, as Rob quoted official docs it seems that it's indeed referring to methods and functions (even though the docs are not 100% clear as they always say "normally" which implicates to me that there are exceptions). If it were limited to the current scope only, it would be quite narrow because I can have an arbitrary number of scopes within a function or method. Heck, I could even open a new scope for every new line by simply enclosing it in braces. Also, every if/for/while etc. control statement opens a new scope. So I think it is referring to the function or method scope.

Comment: Well if you did it inside a 'subscope' like if(someBool==YES) {.....}  then yes, s will only work inside there and you'll have an error and won't even compile if you try to address s outside of that.  Wether these docs are guaranteeing the objects survival to the end of the outer scope is irrelevant, you no longer have any pointer to test this with :)

Comment: I could declare it "static" and it will survive the scope :)

Comment: The non-“normal” cases are documented in the [“Avoid Causing Deallocation of Objects You’re Using” section of the guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-1000922-BABBFBGJ). There are two: when the object came from a container and you remove it from the container, and when you deallocate the sole owner of the object of interest. Note that using ARC protects you from these cases. **Just use ARC!**

Answer (score 1):

There are two documents you should read if you want to understand manual memory management in Cocoa:

- [*Cocoa Core Competencies: Memory Management*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH27-SW1)
- [*Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1), which (in spite of its name) is a good basic introduction.

Here's what the Core Competencies says about receiving an unowned object:

> If you receive an object from elsewhere in your program, it is normally guaranteed to remain valid within the method or function it was received in. If you want it to remain valid beyond that scope, you should retain or copy it.

And here's what the Advanced Guide says:

> A received object is normally guaranteed to remain valid within the method it was received in, and that method may also safely return the object to its invoker. You use retain in two situations: (1) In the implementation of an accessor method or an init method, to take ownership of an object you want to store as a property value; and (2) To prevent an object from being invalidated as a side-effect of some other operation (as explained in Avoid Causing Deallocation of Objects You’re Using).